# How to get rid of column name every time from jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql) in spring boot in java sql

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

Here is the code:

```
public void readOperation() {
        String sql="select * from std";
        List list=jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
        
   for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

I have tried too much to print like this way

```
id name father
2451 mofiz kudda
1524 ahsan abdullah
```

but it always print like this way:

```
{id=2451, name=mofiz, father=kudda}
{id=1524, name=ahsan, father=abdullah}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spring, we can use jdbcTemplate.query() to query records from the database and convert the rows into Object List via row mapper, override toString() method in the object to print the data.

```
public void readOperation()
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM STD";
    List<Std> stds = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (rs, rowNum) -> new Std(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("father")));

    for (Std std : stds)
        std.toString();
}

public class Std
{
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String father;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        buff.append(this.id).append(" ").append(this.name).append(" ").append(this.father);
        return buff.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the error:

Error:(69, 66) java: constructor Std in class com.ahsan.ahsan_new.AhsanNewApplication.Std cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: I haven't written complete class of Std, Please add getters and setters and also create the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

jdbcTemplate.queryForList returns a List<Map<String,Object>> and if you pass this list to System.out.println this it calls the toString method of List and then of Map and the entries. That's why the output looks the way you tet it.

You have to write code to print it like this.

```
System.out.println("id\\tname\\tfather");
for(Map<String,Object> map : list) {
    System.out.println(map.get("id") + "\\t" + map.get("name") + "\\t" + map.get("father"));
}
```

Comment: This error is happening:
Error:(70, 38) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>

Comment: Debug and check what the Objects type is at runtime